# Nicematrix: Package pgf Error: No shape named X is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

I want to add dimensions to the outside of a matrix using the `nicematrix`package, but I run into this Package pgf error:
`! Package pgf Error: No shape named 'nm-1-col-0' is known.`

I have tried to replicate an example from the nicematrix documentation http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf section 15.3 on page 32. This is my MWE (I'm using XeLatex, not sure if it matters):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
D = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
& & & \Ldots[line-style={solid,<->},shorten=0pt]^{p+1} \\
& 0 & 1 & & & \\
& & 0 & 1 & & \\
\Vdots[line-style={solid,<->}]_{p+1}& & & \Ddots & \Ddots & \\
& & & & \Ddots & 1 \\
& & & & & 0 \end{bNiceMatrix} \otimes I_n
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, the example from the `nicematrix` documentation gives the exact same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
{nullify-dots,code-for-first-col = \color{blue},code-for-first-col=\color{blue}}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
& & \Ldots[line-style={solid,<->},shorten=0pt]^{n \text{ columns}} \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 & \Ldots & 1 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 \\
\Vdots[line-style={solid,<->}]_{n \text{ rows}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 & \Ldots & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no errors, neither when compiling with XeLaTeX, nor with pdfLaTeX. Update your LaTeX distribution (TexLive or MikTeX).

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). I think that your TeX installation is not up-to-date. If you want, you can send me by email the `log` file corresponding to your (aborted) compilation : `fpantigny@wanadoo.fr`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny that is a very nice offer, thank you. As I was writing to you by email, I realised I could at least check for updates. I never realised this could be the problem and  I generally can't read the output well enough to understand where the problem truly lies. Among my updates were ones for `nicematrix` and `pgf` and, now it works! Thank you very much. If you add an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update your TeX distribution (`TeXLive`, `MikTeX` of `MacTeX`). In particular, `nicematrix` is a recent package (2018) with frequent updates.